# Unique value under several conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have request for pulling the unique data per several conditions and I get stucked now. Can anyone suggest how to solve this problem?

Table will look like this:

```
Date      |ID | TicketNumber  | Category   | Subcategory|TCount1| TCount2|TCount3

01.04.2017| 1 | 11111         | OldMachine | DDD        | 1     |  2     | 3
01.04.2017| 1 | 13451         | OldMachine | DDD        | 1     |  2     | 3
01.04.2017| 1 | 14343         | OldMachine | DDD        | 1     |  2     | 3
01.04.2017| 2 | 22222         | New Machine| FFD        | 2     |  5     | 8
02.04.2017| 2 | 22222         | New Machine| FFD        | 9     |  7     | 9
```

I should get:

```
For 01.04.2017 for ID=1

01.04.2017| 1 | 11111         | OldMachine | DDD        | 1     |  2     | 3
01.04.2017| 1 | 13451         | OldMachine | DDD        | 1     |  2     | 3
01.04.2017| 1 | 14343         | OldMachine | DDD        | 1     |  2     | 3
```

---

```
For 02.04.2017 for ID=2

02.04.2017| 2 | 22222         | New Machine| FFD        | 9     |  7     | 9
```

I need to count for each ID total TCounts but:

1. In case that one TicketNumbers repeating I need to take last one and count only for that one.
2. Each ID contains sum of all TicketNumbers per some date.
3. Category and subcategory can change during the one day for some ID.

Anyone some idea?

Thanks

I have tried:

```
select t1.date, t1.id, t1.ticketnumber
from schema.table t1
inner join 
(select max(schema.table.date) as maxdate, schema.table.id,schema.table.ticketnumber,          
 from schema.table 
 GROUP BY schema.table.id,schema.table.ticketnumber) t2
 on t2.id = t1.id 
 and t2.maxdate = t1.date;
```

But that returns all ID with all ticketnumber (not uniques).

Comment: You should edit your question and show the results that you want.  Also, why would you sum an id like `TicketNumber`?

Comment: Hi, I have edit some stuff. I have two cases: First need to count different/unique ticketnumbers. Second need to sum each ticket(unique) and then sum all od that per ID per that day. I will post my example but it shown me duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

*In case that one TicketNumbers repeating I need to take last one and count only for that one.*

```
select TicketNumber, count(TicketNumber) as ticketcount
from your_table a
inner join (select max(id) as maxid from your_table) b where a.id = b.id) 
group by TicketNumber
```

*Each ID contains sum of all TicketNumbers per some date.*

```
select outer.Date, outer.ID, inner.ticketcount, sum(inner.ticketcount)
from your_table outer
inner join ( select TicketNumber, count(TicketNumber) as ticketcount
             from your_table a
             inner join (select max(id) as maxid from your_table) b 
             where a.id = b.id) 
             group by TicketNumber ) inner
  on inner.TicketNumber = outer.TicketNumber
group by outer.Date, outer.ID, inner.ticketcount
```

*Category and subcategory can change during the one day for some ID.*

```
select yt.Date
       , yt.ID, 
       , yt.TicketNumber
       , yt.Category
       , yt.SubCategory
       , t2.ticketcount as TCount1
       , t2.sumticket as TCount2
       , count(yt.ID) as TCount3
from your_table yt
inner join (select Date, ticketcount, sum(ticketcount) as sumticket
      from your_table outer
      inner join ( select TicketNumber, count(TicketNumber) as ticketcount
                   from your_table a
                   inner join (select max(id) as maxid from your_table) b 
                   on a.id = b.id 
                   group by TicketNumber ) inner
       on inner.TicketNumber = outer.TicketNumber
       group by Date, ticketcount) t2
  on yt.Date = t2.Date
  group by yt.Date
          , yt.ID, 
          , yt.TicketNumber
          , yt.Category
          , yt.SubCategory
          , t2.ticketcount
          , t2.sumticket
```

This assume that your TCount1 means your case number 1, Tcount2 for your case number 2 and Tcount3 for your case 3 in the list.

Comment: Thanks I will try now and let you know. One thing sum is TCount1+TCount2+TCount3, it is important to be per each row. Thanks on help!